# Upgrade from d3 3.1.9 to 3.1.10 break animations

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

After upgrading from d3 3.1.**9** to 3.1.**10**, animations on my d3 svg visualizations broke.
My guess it's related to this commit (removal of old functionality), and that I'm using an old api.
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/commit/d9659b6794fa1985c756d2a7d8ee73174e54ee08

Even the most simple transition fails (moving a group element 75 pixels to the right):

> d3.select('g.slider').transition().duration(500).attr('transform','translate(100,0)');

I have similar transitions on other elements that will start the same time as above transition. Could there be a conflict where transitions cancel each others, even though they're on completely different elements? I hope I'm just using the (new?) API the wrong way?
Please note that it all worked great on 3.1.9. I've tried following this guide from Mike (transitions with d3.js 3), but the api looks the same, so I'm stuck:
http://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/

edit: I'd be surprised if I'm the only one experiencing this issue. All visualizations with animations I've created over the years with d3 stopped working when moving from 3.1.9 to 3.1.10

Comment: if you think this is a bug in D3, file it with D3, and help everybody get an improved D3.js =) https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues

Answer (score 2):

Please use [GitHub issues](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues) to report bugs.

And please create a full example that demonstrates your unexpected behavior rather than quoting a code snippet out of context. I can’t reproduce the behavior you’ve described. Here is your snippet working correctly inside a full example, http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/b4e46124258d1b75accb:

```
slider.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("transform", "translate(100,0)");
```

D3 has thousands of tests and hundreds of examples, many of which include transitions and animations, and none of which were affected by this change. Do all of your visualizations use this obscure, undocumented feature in d3.timer? I’m very surprised that this change affected your code, and I definitely don’t expect it to be widespread.

Please followup on GitHub issues if you are still experiencing unexpected behavior and can provide more detail for me to investigate.

Comment: Sorry for no including a full example, I'll start working on that and file an issue with it. I was hoping I was just using an old api and that it's not an issue with d3 itself. I'm not using the d3 timer api, just very simple transitions like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having issues with transitions in d3 >= 3.1.10, I was loading [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) library which breaks d3.js due to overloading the Date.now() method.
I suggest not to use date.js, but here's an issue which aims to have d3 do something more graceful instead of silently failing.
See this d3 issue: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1302